# Yahoo YQL geoCode not returning country in php

Tags: php, google-maps

We are using Yahoo YQL geo code finder to find a country code using the latitude and longitude.

Following is the url used,

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+geo.placefinder+where+text+%3D+%2751.5073509%2C+-0.12775829999998223%27+and+gflags%3D%27R%27+&format=json
```

It used to work earlier, but suddenly it has stopped providing the country code.

Following is the result given,

```
{"query":{"count":0,"created":"2016-02-11T06:35:28Z","lang":"en-US","results":null}}
```

Please help me to find a solution for this.

Regards,

Neha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which works fine in my case.

The yahoo API service is unavailable for query format, hence I have used the below format.

http://gws2.maps.yahoo.com/findlocation?q=51.5073509%2C%20-0.12775829999998223&gflags=R&format=json

Regards,

Neha

Answer (score 0):

Checking the yahoo console. I can't find any reference for the table `geo.placefinder`

Are you sure that you are using the correct API and the correct parameter.

I have run a geo location query

```
select * from geo.places where text= "SFO"
```

[http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+geo.places+where+text+=+%27SFO](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%20=%20%27SFO)

Which gives me the following result

> {"query":{"count":1,"created":"2016-02-11T08:09:34Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"place":{"lang":"en-US","xmlns":"http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng","yahoo":"http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng","uri":"http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/12521721","woeid":"12521721","placeTypeName":{"code":"14","content":"Airport"},"name":"San
>   Francisco International
>   Airport","country":{"code":"US","type":"Country","woeid":"23424977","content":"United
>   States"},"admin1":{"code":"US-CA","type":"State","woeid":"2347563","content":"California"},"admin2":{"code":"","type":"County","woeid":"12587707","content":"San
>   Francisco"},"admin3":null,"locality1":{"type":"Town","woeid":"2487956","content":"San
>   Francisco"},"locality2":null,"postal":{"type":"Zip
>   Code","woeid":"12797178","content":"94128"},"centroid":{"latitude":"37.62207","longitude":"-122.383659"},"boundingBox":{"southWest":{"latitude":"37.603939","longitude":"-122.403732"},"northEast":{"latitude":"37.64463","longitude":"-122.35482"}},"areaRank":"1","popRank":"1","timezone":{"type":"Time
>   Zone","woeid":"56043663","content":"America/Los_Angeles"}}}}}

Sorry for the hard format, I can't get the tags to work the way I want it.

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT+*+FROM+geo.places+WHERE+text%3D%2251.5073509%22